# Is there a way to "compass compile" into specified file path?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, compass-sass, sass

I am building an ExtJS 4 application backed by SASS/Compass for its theme.

I would like to generate 2 files:

1. my-ext-theme.css
2. my-ext-theme.min.css

I currently have a "my-ext-theme.scss" file that I am successfully compiling to "my-ext-theme.css".  The issue is that I want 1 scss file to compile to 2+ css files.  Additionally, I would like those css files to be in any directory I want.

Note: I **do not** want to add a config.rb file so that it outputs "only" to different directories (i.e. "css/my-ext-theme.css" and "css2/my-ext-theme.css").

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Current Solution (little annoying)**

```
my-ext-theme.scss // my sass code here
my-ext-theme.min.scss // @import 'my-ext-theme';

compass compile my-ext-theme.scss // development
compass compile --output-style compressed my-ext-theme.min.scss // production
```